# Must the center of a group be Abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

Must the center of a group be Abelian?

We know Abelian means commutative. And the center is a set of elements that commute with everybody. Does this mean EVERY center is Abelian?

Comment: Yes. The elements of the centre commute with every element of the group, in particular with the other elements of the centre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that when you say *the center of any group is Abelian* you are implicitly assuming that *the center of any group is, itself, a group*. This latter statement is true (and a good exercise for a first course on Group Theory) but it should not be swept under the rug.

Secondly (i.e., once you have established that the center is a group) you could reason as follows:

Let $G$ be a group, and let $Z(G)$ be its center, i.e., the elements of $G$ that commute with any other element of $G$.

Then: Given any $x, y \in Z(G)$, we know that $x$ (since it's in the center of the group) commutes with any other element of $G$; in particular, $x$ commutes with $y$, that is, $xy = yx$. Since $x$ and $y$ were chosen to be arbitrary elements of the center, we conclude that $Z(G)$ is Abelian. **QED**